# unable to access DB pod External IP from application

Tags: azure, kubernetes, containers, kubectl, azure-container-service

I've created two pods top of Azure Kubernetes cluster
1) Application
2) MS SQL server

both pods are exposed via Azure Loadbalancer and both having External IPs. I am unable to use the External IP in my application config file. But I can connect that SQL Server from anywhere. For some reason I am unable to telnet DB IP from Application container.

the connection is getting timeout. but I can ping/telnet the DB's cluster ip. So I have tried to use the DB cluster IP in my config file to check if the connection is successful but no luck.

Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: Are you sure you are pinging Pod IP instead of cluster ip ? AFAIK , You can not ping cluster IP you can do nslookup with it .

Comment: can you provide the result of following command in `kubectl get ep,svc` ?

Comment: hi, here is the output

https://ibb.co/cqCvSw

10.0.107.211 is my DB container. 10.0.176.132 is my application container. I can ping the DB container from my application container.

Comment: my issues is, I want to point this DB in my connection string. Since I cannot access the DB external IP from Application container. The connection was unsuccessful... 

Its quite Urgent issue. Any quick help greatly appreciated. THanks

Comment: you can ping pod address 10.244.2.212  and 10.244.0.54 these address, are you able to ping these service address ( 10.0.107.211 10.0.176.132 ) as well ?

Comment: If you provide the name of the 'db pod' to the 'app pod' it will resolve the address by kube-dns

Comment: I have added a link it might give your some reasonable thoughts https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-kubernetes-networking-services-f0cb48e4cc82

Comment: hi, I have tried providing DB pod name in the connection string. its not working.

Comment: is Kube-dns working in the cluster?

Comment: when i check "kubectl exec -it sqlserverstatefulset-0 -- nslookup kubernetes.default"
I got the response

Server:  kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
Address:  10.0.0.10

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    kubernetes.default
Address:  10.0.0.1

Comment: my problem is, from application pod, I'm unable to hit the DB external IP. If I could hit DB service external IP then my issue will be fixed

Comment: If both of the services are part of the k8s cluster, why are you using external IP ? It is better to use cluster IP for service discovery and communication. 
I think you should try to hit the DB cluster IP it might work

Comment: I tried that way (providing Db cluster IP) but it doesn't work.
**************************************

PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -HostName "10.0.36.86" -Username "sa" -Password "xxxx" -Query "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases"
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Hi @SureshVishnoi its getting really weird for me. I can telnet the DB cluster IP with 1433. but when I specify the cluster IP as DB host its not connecting. I am using mssql-server-windows-express docker image in my DB container.

Comment: I think If you can telnet to the db app then issue might be with Layer7 or redirection of packets at that level

Comment: so what could be the solution for this ? Do you have any clue for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed..!

Create two pods for Application and DB, Earlier when I provide the DB cluster IP in application config file, it was worked.But I was able to telnet  1433

I have created another K8s cluster in Azure then tried with same setup (provided cluster IP). This time it worked like charm.

Thanks to @Suresh Vishnoi

Answer (score 0):

As Suresh said, we should not use public IP address to connect them.

We can refer to this [article](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/) to create a application and a database, then connect a front end to a back end using a service.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post, I am using MS SQL Express as backend service,  I need to specify the SQL connection string in my application web.config file..

If I refer this link, what should be my connection string ?
********
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/

Comment: its urgent issue, any help would greatly appreciated..!! @Jason Ye - MSFT

Comment: I've followed the link you mentioned. But still I'm unable to access the DB service.. here is the error https://ibb.co/hdedjb

Comment: Yes, I can ran Invoke-Sqlcmd from local machine.. I use service external IP to access it.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue was fixed in other way.** But still running a Application & DB as separate service is night mare in Azure container service(Kubernetes).

1) I've combined App+DB in same container and put the DB connection string as "localhost" or "localhost,1433" is my application config file.

2) Created Docker image with above setup

3) Created pod

4) Exposed pod with two listening ports "kubectl expose pods "xxx" --port=80,1433 --type=LoadBalancer

5) I can access the DB with 1433

**In the above setup, we have planned to keep the container in auto scaled environment with persistent volume storage
Also we are planning to do the scheduled backup of container, So we do not want to loose the DB data.**

**Is anybody having other thoughts, what the major issue factors we need to consider in above setup ??**

Comment: I think you have made it as a monolithic system which is a contrast to the K8s philosophy. In this solutions, there is no isolation of service. For Instance, If you want to update your app,  DB will need to be redeployed.

Comment: Hi @SureshVishnoi yes, it is not complete micro service architecture and when there is a change in the Application/DB we need to rebuild the container with reimage.


This is what i'm wondering and why the previous method was not successful (i.e. App & DB running in a separate POD)? Still I couldn't figured it out why the connection string in application web.config doesn't take the DB cluster IP / DB pod name.

Comment: hi, anyone having answer for this ?